# How do I have all constructors by default call a method without using inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop

For example I would like to have all the constructors of `MyClass` always calls `foo()`. But as you can see below, the way I am doing has code duplication. Is there a more elegant way to do this, without having `MyClass` extend from a super class?:

```
class MyClass{
  MyClass();
  MyClass(int);
  MyClass(int, int);
  private:
  void foo();
}

MyClass::MyClass(){
   foo(); //repetitive
}

MyClass::MyClass(int a){
  foo(); //repetitive
}

MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b){
  foo(); //repetitive
}
```

Comment: How about delegating constructors?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Bear in mind that delegating constructors are invalid before C++11.

Comment: @Peter: We have 2017 and the question was not tagged C++03.

Comment: @Klaus - It was tagged C++, which is a tag that has been around for several years during which a number C++ standards have been drafted and ratified, with numerous questions and answers about them.  You can't seriously expect all questions that were tagged C++ more than roughly a month ago (the timing of the DRAFT March 2017 standard) must somehow be revisited and updated to account for any differences between C++17 draft and previous standards.

Answer (score 0):

Question is answered by [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler). I can use [delegating constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn387583.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: You can certainly use a delegating constructor, but how will it solve the code duplication issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an easy fix, **why not define an abstract class that contains method foo?** and that method foo() is called in default constrcutor , Now all you need to do is to inherit that class .

Comment: You suggest to call **virtual** method from constructor ?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: If you call virtual method, you will call pure virtual call -> UB.

Comment: Call a method from the constructor of the class and inherit that class. Why you are associating it with virtual function ?

Comment: **abstract class** ? That why providing code is clearer that just sentence that we can misinterpret...

Comment: Try using a protected constructor instead